# Uncommenting `if False: yield` changes `__iter__` behaviour

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I cannot figure why the behavior of `__iter__` changes when I uncomment `if False: yield`. The condition is never true, so why does the result change?

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = [1,2,3]
        self.size = 3

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        #if False: yield 
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n > self.size:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.lst[self.n-1]

ex = Example()
for i in ex:
    print(i)
```

In this code everything works as expected, and it prints out the list.

If I uncomment the the `if False: yield` in the `__iter__` method then the iterator stops working and nothing gets printed out, even if that line never gets executed.

Comment: what you find is the subtle difference between a Iterator and Iterable objects in python

Answer (score 3):

When you uncomment your line `if False: yield` the Python interpreter will compile the `def __iter__(self)` into a `generator` rather than a function. A generator is an iterator encapsulated in a function that will keep returning values (on `next` calls) for as long as `yield` statements keep providing values and will raise a `StopIteration` when the generator returns out of its function:

```py
>>> class A:
...  def __iter__(self):
...    if False:
...      yield
...
>>> a = A()
>>> type(iter(a))
<class 'generator'>
>>> class B:
...   def __iter__(self):
...     return self
...   def __next__(self):
...     return 1
...
>>> type(iter(B()))
<class '__main__.B'>
```

When you comment the line your `__iter__` is a regular function and returns `self` as an iterator, any class that implements a `__next__` method can be used as an iterator; if you hadn't you'd get this error:

```py
>>> class B:
...   def __iter__(self):
...     return self
...
>>> type(iter(B()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'B'
```

Note that if all `__iter__` does is return `self` that you don't even need to implement it, just `__next__` would suffice. Your `__iter__` implementation is even dangerous: Multiple `iter(ex)` calls will all return the same `ex` object as iterator and will reset the `n` of all these "iterators" actually using the same `ex`:

```py
>>> ex = Example()
>>> itr1 = iter(ex)
>>> print(next(itr1), next(itr1))
1 2
>>> iter(ex)
>>> print(next(itr1))
1
```

Calling `iter` again resets your previous iterator reference? I can't imagine that's what you are trying to achieve ;)

Answer (score -2):

The `if` loop never executes if the condition is `False`. So, when you use `if False:` since the condition is `False` it never executes. Also, you don't have anything specified in `yield`.

This can be rewritten as,

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = [1,2,3]
        self.size = 3
        self.n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        for i in self.lst:
            yield i

    def __next__(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n > self.size:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.lst[self.n-1]

ex = Example()
for i in ex:
    print(i)
```

The output will be as desired.

Comment: Hi maney, my question was related to the fact that the if False line breaks the code even if it is never run. Do you know why?

Comment: when specified `yield` the function is converted to generator. So, it is a generator now but it wont yield anything since the `if` loop is `False`.